# Why and How to mock Model-Helperclasses?

Tags: java, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

I am reading a lot about unit testing, mocking, and all that stuff. I am currently also reading the book "Growing Object-Oriented Software Guided by Tests" by Steve Freeman and Nat Pryce.

I am starting to understand a lot of stuff but missing one crucial point, where I tried to find the answer anywhere online but am not satisfied yet.

In the following example I have an Online Shop, which receives messages from a third-party library, translates those, interpret them and eventually persist them into the database if needed. In a concrete case, I receive a message about a change of the address of a credit card of a user and want to store that information into a database.

The structure looks like this:

```
src/
     domain/
           MessageTranslator.java
           ShopEventListener.java
           ShopHandler.java
     model/
           CreditCard.java
           CreditCardBase.java
           CreditCardBuilder.java
           User.java
           UserBase.java
           UserBuilder.java
test/
     MessageTranslatorTest.java
     ShopHandlerTest.java
```

**MessageTranslatorTest**

```
public class MessageTranslatorTest {


    @Test
    public void notifiesCCAddressChangedWhenChangeCCAddressMessageReceived() throws Exception {
        ShopEventListener listenerMock = mock(ShopEventListener.class);

        MessageTranslator messageTranslator = new MessageTranslator(listenerMock);
        messageTranslator.processMessage("action=changeCCAddress; firstname=John; lastname=Doe; address=foobar3");

        verify(listenerMock).ccAddressChanged("John", "Doe", "foobar3");
    }
}
```

**MessageTranslator** (very simple for now)

```
public class MessageTranslator {

    private final ShopEventListener listener;

    public MessageTranslator(ShopEventListener userEventListener) {
        listener = userEventListener;
    }

    public void processMessage(String message) throws Exception {
        String[] attributes = message.split(";");       
        listener.ccAddressChanged(attributes[1].split("=")[1].trim(), attributes[2].split("=")[1].trim(), attributes[3].split("=")[1].trim());      
    }

}
```

**ShopHandler**

```
public class ShopHandler implements ShopEventListener {

    @Override
    public void ccAddressChanged(String firstname, String lastname, String newAddress) throws Exception {

        // find a user (especially userid) in the Database for given firstname and lastname 
        UserBase userBase = new UserBase();
        User user = userBase.find(aUser().withFirstname(firstname).withLastname(lastname).build());

        if (user == null) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        // find the matching CreditCard for the userid in the database
        Integer userid = user.getUserid();
        CreditCardBase ccBase = new CreditCardBase();
        CreditCard cc = ccBase.find(aCreditCard().withUserid(userid).build());

        if (cc == null) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        // change address locally and then write it back to the database
        cc.setAddress(newAddress);
        cc.persist();
    }

}
```

**ShopHandlerTest**

```
public class ShopHandlerTest {

    @Test
    public void changesCCAddressWhenChangeCCAddressEventReceived() throws Exception {
        ShopHandler shop = new ShopHandler();
        shop.ccAddressChanged("John", "Doe", "foobar3");

        // TODO: How to test the changes in inner object?
    }

}
```

This is where I always stumble.

1. Do I want to mock the helper classes UserBase and CreditCardBase to not perform any database queries but just return a prepared fake object?
2. Do I want to mock the persist-method to not write any real data to the database but maybe just test the parameters of the object to be persisted and have other (integration) tests test the database operations?
3. If 1. and 2. will be answered with yes, then what am I actually testing here? Is it worth unittesting this unit then?
4. Does the structure make sense this way?
5. If 1. and 2. will be answered with yes, then how do I mock the inner objects? I feel like dependency injection is the wront approach here, because first its no real dependency, but some helper classes, second (and more important imo) the ShopHandler class could be flooded with dependencies, as it might need alot of different helper classes and model classes to perform all the different actions. What if I just want to update the birthdate of a user based on an external message, do I still have to path all the dependencies like CreditCardBase and stuff?

Sorry for the long post, but it would be really awesome if you could push me in the right direction.
If you need more code for the above to understand, let me know.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153447/discussion-on-question-by-dg-vs-why-and-how-to-mock-model-helperclasses). If you have meaningful opinions that you want to share about unit testing and/or mocking, then *post an answer*!

Answer (score 1):

> Do I want to mock the helper classes UserBase and CreditCardBase to not perform any database queries but just return a prepared fake object?

Looks like your "helper classes" are actually repositories/DAOs. You normally want to test your business logic separately from DAOs, without the real database access. So yes, you should probably mock these DAOs and prepare the calls to them as they *would* work in reality. Prepared fake object is OK in most cases. You may also want to verify that your mocked DAO was actually called.

> Do I want to mock the persist-method to not write any real data to the database but maybe just test the parameters of the object to be persisted and have other (integration) tests test the database operations?

I find it a bit strange that you seem to have the `persist` method in your business entity. Normally DAOs implement this type of methods.

Yes, if you test business logic you should mock the `persist` call to DAOs as well. If you don't do this, you'll be making tests of the business logic much heavier that they should be.

Yes, you should test your DAOs as well but separately from the business logic.

> If 1. and 2. will be answered with yes, then what am I actually testing here? Is it worth unittesting this unit then?

You're testing you business logic. Just what is implemented in your `ccAddressChanged` method. Roughly:

- if the user could not be found, an exception is thrown.
- if user is found but users credit card could not be found, an exception is thrown.
- if both could be found then credit card is persisted with an updated address.

> Does the structure make sense this way?

It is not quite what I'm used to. You seem to have data access logic in entities, then you also have this "base" helper classess...

> If 1. and 2. will be answered with yes, then how do I mock the inner objects?

With "inner objects" you probaby mean these helper classes. They are actually more that "helper classes", they are DAOs providing access to the database. You can pass or inject them from the outside. Basically this is dependency injection, your business logic depends on these DAO components. If you are able to pass them from the outside then in your test you can mock DAOs and pass mocks to your business service. With DI frameworks like Spring you'll have framework support for this.

Here'a a rough sketch of how a test for your `ShopHandler` class could look like with Spring and Mockito:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ShopHandler.class})
public class ShopHandlerTest {

    @Autowired
    private ShopHandler sut;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @MockBean
    private CreditCardRepository creditCardRepository;

    @Test(expected = UserNotFoundException.class)
    public void throwsUserNotFoundExceptionIfUserIsUnknown() {
        when(userRepository.findUserByFirstNameAndLastName("Scott", "Tiger").thenReturn(null);

        sut.ccAddressChanged("Scott", "Tiger", "Some Address");
    }

    @Test
    public void successFullyUpdatesCreditCardAddress() {
        when(userRepository.findUserByFirstNameAndLastName("Scott", "Tiger").thenReturn(new User("userId", ...));
        when(creditCardRepository.findByUserId("userId")).thenReturn(new CreditCard(...));

        ArgumentCaptor<CreditCard> creditCardCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(CreditCard.class);

        verify(creditCardRepository).save(creditCardCaptor.capture());

        sut.ccAddressChanged("Scott", "Tiger", "Some Address");

        asserthThat(creditCardCaptor.getValue().getAddress()).isEqualTo("Some Address");
    }
}
```

> I feel like dependency injection is the wront approach here,

Dependency injection is a very sensible approach here.

> because first its no real dependency,

Well, *of course* these are real dependencies.

> but some helper classes,

Where do you think it end being a "helper class" and starts being a "real dependency"? What you call "helper classes" pretty much resemble DAOs which absolutely are "real dependencies".

> second (and more important imo) the ShopHandler class could be flooded with dependencies, as it might need alot of different helper classes and model classes to perform all the different actions.

If you need to perform all these actions and need all these dependencies to do this, then this is the reality. The question is, however - do you really have to implement all of these actions in just one business service? Can't you divide this into many business services? You'll get smaller more focused classes then, and they will only need a few dependencies.

Comment: This was very helpful. Thank you. You write that this is not the structure you are normally used to. And also related to your last point, can you shortly describe how a better structure would be? Maybe this will help me sort out the problem with the flooded DI.

Comment: @dg.vs This is a pretty broad question which would take a good book (like [this one](https://martinfowler.com/books/eaa.html)) to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're creating `UserBase` and `CreditCard` instances using `new` keyword in the method `ccAddressChanged()` - you cannot mock them!

In order to be able to mock them use DI - [Dependency Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) (also called IoC - [Inversion Of Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)) by injecting instances of these class to `ccAddressChanged()`:

change the signature of the class from:

```
public void ccAddressChanged(String firstname, String lastname, String newAddress)
```

to:

```
public void ccAddressChanged(String firstname, String lastname, String newAddress, UserBase userBase, CreditCard creditCard)
```

This way, you'll be able to mock them (using Mockito or any other mocking framework) and sending the mocks to the method.

Example of how the test will look, using Mockito:

```
@Test
public void changesCCAddressWhenChangeCCAddressEventReceived() throws Exception {
    ShopHandler shop = new ShopHandler();
    // mock UserBase and its behavior
    UserBase mockedUserBase = mock(UserBase.class)
    when(mockedUserBase.find(any()).thenReturns(mock(User.class));

    // mock CreditCard
    CreditCard mockedCreditCard = mock(CreditCard.class);
    shop.ccAddressChanged("John", "Doe", "foobar3");
}
```

> I feel like dependency injection is the wrong approach here, because
>   first its no real dependency, but some helper classes, second (and
>   more important imo) the ShopHandler class could be flooded with
>   dependencies

DI is *not* wrong:

1. It seems that `ShopHandler` class *does* have a real dependency on `UserBase` and `CreditCardBase`
2. To avoid "flooded" scenario you can inject them into the constructor of `ShopHandler` and save them into private fields. This way it's done only once during initialization and does not burden the user as well as doesn't expose implementation details.

Further, assuming that you refactored your code and now you're assigning `UserBase` and `CreditCardBase` in the constructor. I would refactor the code from:

```
@Override
public void ccAddressChanged(String firstname, String lastname, String newAddress) throws Exception {

    // find a user (especially userid) in the Database for given firstname and lastname 
    UserBase userBase = new UserBase();
    User user = userBase.find(aUser().withFirstname(firstname).withLastname(lastname).build());

    if (user == null) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    // find the matching CreditCard for the userid in the database
    Integer userid = user.getUserid();
    CreditCardBase ccBase = new CreditCardBase();
    CreditCard cc = ccBase.find(aCreditCard().withUserid(userid).build());

    if (cc == null) {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    // change address locally and then write it back to the database
    cc.setAddress(newAddress);
    cc.persist();
}
```

to:

```
@Override
public void ccAddressChanged(String firstname, String lastname, String newAddress) throws Exception {
    User user = getUserByName(firstname, lastname);
    CreditCard creditCard = getCCByUser(user);
    setAddress(creditCard, newAddress);
}
```

and now you don't have to unit-test this `ccAddressChanged()` anymore. What you *should* do is test, and each one of the three methods: `getUserByName`, `getCCByUser` and `setAddress`. And each one of them is easy to mock and test!

Comment: Yes, I know that I can not mock it this way and that I would need DI. See point 5 of my numbered list. The question was whether it makes sense at all to mock out the calls or not. And if it makes sense, what should the DI or even the overall structure look like. Injecting all needed objects into the method directly could blow it and also forces the caller to know alot about the domain specific knowledge of the called unit.

Comment: @dg.vs variables that you can re-use you should inject at the constructor - this will help you avoid putting the burden on the caller to provide these arguments upon any call, and this way you'll have to initialize them only once. I added another paragraph to the answer.

Comment: Firstly, "Inversion of Control" has nothing to do with DI (yes, those wikipedia articles are wrong - correct definitions can be found in articles from Martin Fowler). Secondly, while `UserBase` and `CreditCardBase` are good candidates for being injected (as they are stateless non-objects), they can still be mocked (easily and with clean unit tests, using JMockit) while being "new-ed" in the tested code.

Comment: @Rogério if you're referring to what he wrote [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/InversionOfControl.html) then I'm afraid you misunderstood him. About JMockit - I'd love to learn how - mind putting here a link that demos it ?

Comment: Yes, in that article Fowler explains that IoC is an older concept, which came from libraries ("frameworks") where the client developer passes in an object which the framework later calls back on, therefore "inverting" the usual flow of control. Fowler also wrote [this article](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html), where he actually *coined* the name "dependency injection", while explaining why "inversion of control" wasn't appropriate. With JMockit, to mock `UserBase` you would simply declare a `@Mocked UserBase ub` field or parameter, then record expectations on `ub`.

Comment: @Rogério he wrote: "As a result I think we need a more specific name for this pattern. Inversion of Control is too generic a term, and thus people find it confusing. As a result with a lot of discussion with various IoC advocates we settled on the name Dependency Injection."

Comment: @Rogério all he's saying is that IoC is a more general term which has different meanings in different contexts and this "overloading" could be confusing so he suggests a "more specific" name: DI. Saying that "Inversion of Control" has nothing to do with DI is a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @alfasin Ok, I get what you say: in the end, we *could* admit the use of "inversion of control" for the injection of dependencies. But that would be a big stretch, and an abuse, of the original meaning of IoC. My interpretation of Fowler's article is that he simply didn't want to come out and say that Rod Johnson (creator of Spring and the one who first misused the IoC concept) had lacked imagination and screwed up by abusing an existing name/concept (IoC) for a new idea (DI). My point is that people should try to avoid saying "IoC" when they mean DI.

Comment: @Rogério you're kinda saying that an Audi is *not* a car. While it's true that "Car" is more generic and Audi is more specific, and if you say that a specific car is Audi you'll be more precise, it's still okay (not a big stretch and definitely not an abuse!) if someone points to an Audi and calls it a car. I hope that this metaphor explains it better than I did previously.

Comment: @alfasin To me, the key to it is the word "Control" in "Inversion of Control". IoC is not about any kind of inversion. As Fowler wrote, "Inversion of control is a common characteristic of frameworks", where "The main control of the program was inverted, moved away from you to the framework". It is not "too generic a term", because "control" specifically means the *flow of control between methods*, while Dependency Injection "inverts the *lookup* of the dependency", we could say. So, to me, IoC still has nothing to do with DI. But even if it had, it's still a disservice to conflate the two.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would write integration tests for `ShopHandler` (as shown in the question, with no changes):

```
public class ShopHandlerTest {
    @Tested(fullyUnitialized = true) AppDB appDB;
    @Tested ShopHandler sut;

    @Test(expected = UserNotFoundException.class)
    public void throwsUserNotFoundExceptionIfUserIsUnknown() {
        sut.ccAddressChanged("Unknown", "user", "...");
    }

    @Test
    public void successFullyUpdatesCreditCardAddress() {
        User user = new User("Scott", "Tiger");
        appDB.persist(user);
        CreditCard cc = new CreditCard(user, ...);
        appDB.persist(cc);
        String newAddress = "New address";

        sut.ccAddressChanged(user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(), newAddress);

        appDB.refresh(cc);
        assertEquals(newAddress, cc.getAddress());
    }
}
```

Above, `@Tested` is a JMockit annotation with full DI support, and also JPA/EJB/etc. support. It can be used as a meta-annotation, so you could create a `@SUT` or `@TestUtil` annotation to simplify its use in tests.

The fully-reusable test utility class `AppDB` would be something like this:

```
public final class AppDB {
    @PersistenceContext private EntityManager em;

    @PostConstruct
    private void startTransaction() { ... using em... }

    @PreDestroy
    private void endTransaction() { ... rollback using em... }

    public void persist(Object entity) { em.persist(entity); }
    public void refresh(Object entity) { em.refresh(entity); }
}
```

Notice how nice and simple those integration tests look. They basically only contain high-level code, essentially the same kind of code you would see in the production (SUT) code. No complicated mocking APIs to get you in trouble. They are also fast and stable.